# Perfekt tense "haben" + "Partizip Perfekt" in reverse order

Tags: sentence-structure, perfect-tense

When I was learning German, the teacher told me a rule for the Perfekt tense:

> You conjugate the verb "haben" first and then add the Partizip Perfekt at the end.

An example such as

> Sie hat an der Universität Moderne Sprachen studiert

satisfied my teacher's idea.

However, when I was reading a sentence today, this order did not take place.

> Der Freund, der die Pasta gekocht hat, heißt Moses.

I was wondering, is the relativpronomen "der" causing this order to change? And, why is this the case?

Answer (score 5):

Going by the position of the finite verb, German has three types of sentences: **verb first, verb second** and **verb final**. Each sentence type has multiple uses, but let's look at the basic ones.

- **V1**: yes-no questions, imperative sentences

  > **Hat** sie studiert?
  > **Bring** mir mal bitte ein Bier!
- **V2**: declarative sentences, wh-questions

  > *Sie* **hat** moderne Sprachen studiert. *Gestern* **haben** wir Pasta gegessen.
  > *Was* **hat** sie studiert?
- **V-final**: subordinate sentences (introduced by a conjunction, a relative phrase or a wh-phrase)

  > Ihm ist schlecht, *weil* er zu viel gegessen **hat**.
  > Wie heißt das Fach, *das* sie studiert **hat**?
  > Ich weiß nicht, *wer* das entschieden **hat**.
- Non-finite verbs and verbal particles are always placed at the end of the sentence.

  > Wir haben gestern Pizza **gegessen**.
  > Musst du am Wochenende **arbeiten**?
  > Er ruft jedes Wochenende seine Eltern **an**.
  > Hör mir doch bitte **zu**!

In short, your teacher's rule works for V1 and V2, but not for V-final clauses.

Comment: Stellt sich in einem Witz ein Verb an Position 1 und sagt: »Sprich auch über die Position von Verben in Befehlen!«.

Comment: Die Befehle habe ich ergänzt, bei den Witzen verweigere ich mich :)